# Wordpress admin panel theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, dashboard

I want to create customized theme for admin panel of wordpress.
googled a lot on this but didnt get any solution.
is there any way to customize the admin panel ( not just the css but the html layout also integrated with jquery )
I thought to show the admin panel on a page ( the selected menus and sections like add create post , manage comments ) but how to show them on a wordpress page ( created in theme )

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress doesn't have Admin themes per se but you can change the look and feel of the admin panel by modifying the CSS or using a plugin. Have a look at this page from the Wordpress Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes

Comment: i checked it but it only provide the feature to modify the css and i want to change the layout ( html ) and add some jquery functionality .
there may be some ways to do this ?

Comment: As I said, there is no "theme" you can use, but you can always modify the actual Wordpress code, I have done this in the past to provide clients with a bespoke look and feel to it but you have to be aware that you will have to be careful with Wordpress updates as they will overwrite any changes.

Comment: core hack is the only possible solution for it

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can customize the admin-panel 
Install 'Horizontal admin menu' plugin.
if you are frustrated with old look of admin panel then this will solve it to an extent.

Comment: its not what i need but a nice suggestion, top menu looks good and compact